# PHP Upload Image Path in SQL database

Tags: php, image, upload, path

I have receive certain advices of inserting Image Path into the database instead of Image File itself. But i still have problem cause it does not work at all. May I know how should my SQL table be set if my code is like this? And please do point out my mistakes too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php

session_start();

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';

$dbconnect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("gg");
$dbselect = mysql_select_db('uploadimg', $dbconnect) or die("gg1");

mysql_close($dbconnect);

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload Image Path Into SQL Database</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

//getting the filename of the image file.
$filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

//directory name to be stored.
$path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Test/images";

//uploading the image file with the image file name into the directory.
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$path."/".$filename)) {

//if the image is stored success into the directory then we are going to store into database.

//the real path with the filename.

        $mysql_path = $path."/".$filename;

//sql query to be executed.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO uploadimg(filename,path) VALUES ('$filename','$mysql_path')";

//executing the query.
        if(mysql_query($sql)) {

            echo 'path inserted into database';

        }

        else {

            echo 'path not inserted into database';

        }

    }

    else {

        echo 'file not uploaded';

    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      File:
      <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error? unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are 3 errors in your code:

1. There is an extra closing brace after:

   else {

   ```
   echo 'file not uploaded';
   ```

   }
2. In your mysql_query() function, you have supplied only your query argument, $sql. But for the mysql_query() function, you need to submit your connection variable as well. (In this case $dbconnect). So, your statement will be :

   if(mysql_query($sql,$dbconnect)) {
3. You are closing your database connection immediately after opening it. So the php code for inserting values in the database wont work. Therefore, you have to add your mysql_close() function after all the database work is done, which in this case will be:

   else {

   ```
         echo 'file not uploaded';

     }
   ```

   mysql_close($dbconnect);

   ?>

*Additional Note: I notice you used 'uploadimg' as the name for your database as well as your table. Make sure both have the same name!

Hope that helps!! Cheers

Comment: Hi Thank you much for correcting my mistakes. But may i know what does it mean by the "image" and "name" in this code: $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

Comment: Well, $_FILES is a 2-dimensional array, in which the first parameter, "image" is the name of the form element in your HTML code (<input type ="file" name = "**image**">). The second parameter "name" is one of the 5 additional parameters on files in PHP. They are "name", "type", "size", "tmp_name" and "error". "name" specifies the name of the file that is being uploaded, "type" returns the extension, "size" returns the file size, "tmp_name" specifies the name of the temporary file that is stored in the server while uploading, and "error" returns the errors(if any) while uploading of the file.